# Datastore RunQuery docs

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Where can I read more of datastore_v3 and RunQuery?
Because from the appengine-go's datastore package, the query.go source seems to use "datastore_v3" and "RunQuery".

What I was trying to understand is how to use the "Distinct" keyword in Go as mentioned from: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference

Thank you.

Comment: According to the syntax summary, you just insert the distinct keyword after your projection: `SELECT id, col, etc DISTINCT FROM ...` and that query will "will only return the first result for entities which have the same values for the properties that are being projected."

Comment: in appengine-go right?

Comment: No, sorry, GQL is only available in Python and the Datastore viewer: https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general?hl=en#gql. It doesn't look like Go supports the "Distinct" keyword as mentioned in the GQL reference you linked. However, there is most likely a way to get the same result with go calls. If you post some code and an example of the result set you're looking for, you might get more of a response.

Comment: As far as datastore_v3.RunQuery, I believe that's an internal RPC function that GAE uses (along with Put, Get, Next). As such, there's not much in the way of documentation to be found on them -- you're not supposed to manipulate them directly in your code.